# SQL Server Query Returning Same Row Twice

Tags: sql, sql-server

I seem to be having trouble with the following query. It basically works, but I have a case where it is returning one row from `mc_WorkoutDetails` twice!

Here's the original query:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[mc_Workouts_GetActivities]
    @WorkoutID                  bigint
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT d.ID, a.Description,
            CASE WHEN Reps = 0 THEN NULL ELSE Reps END AS Reps,
            CASE WHEN Sets = 0 THEN NULL ELSE Sets END AS Sets,
            CASE WHEN Minutes = 0 THEN NULL ELSE Minutes END AS Minutes,
            d.Comments, c.Name AS Category, a.CategoryID,
            (CASE WHEN v.ActivityID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS HasVideo,
            a.ID AS ActivityID
    FROM mc_WorkoutDetails d
            INNER JOIN mc_Activities a ON d.ActivityID = a.ID
            INNER JOIN mc_Activities_Categories c ON a.CategoryID = c.ID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN mc_TrainerVideos v ON a.ID = v.ActivityID
    WHERE (d.WorkoutID = @WorkoutID)
    ORDER BY SortOrder, a.Description

    RETURN @@ERROR
END
```

Then I tried changing:

```
INNER JOIN mc_Activities a ON d.ActivityID = a.ID
INNER JOIN mc_Activities_Categories c ON a.CategoryID = c.ID
```

To:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN mc_Activities a ON d.ActivityID = a.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN mc_Activities_Categories c ON a.CategoryID = c.ID
```

But that didn't seem to help. I still get the duplicate row.

Can anyone see what's happening?

Comment: can you post of the result you are getting now?

Comment: The problem is in the data being used for the joins.  One of the tables has two rows on one of the ids.  We can't really help you with this.  You need to investigate the data.

Comment: @JW: Unfortunately, I can seem to find a way to format a table in a meaningful way here.

Comment: are all values of the column the same for the duplicated row?

Comment: I agree with @GordonLinoff here. You either have a duplicate row in `mc_workoutDetails`, or more likely since it appears the videos are a one-to-many relationship, you have two videos for a single activity.

Comment: To format a table - just use the "code" button like for your code snippets - or just indent the lines of the table by at least four spaces from the left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is add a join back to the same table using a group to weed out the duplicate rows.

So add this to your join after FROM mc_WorkoutDetails d:

```
inner join (select [columns you want to select], max(id) id
            from mc_WorkoutDetails
            group by [columns you want to select] ) q on q.id = d.id
```

Let me know if that makes sense.  Basically you are doing a distinct and getting the max id so you eliminate one of the rows in the join.  You have to remember that even if you want there to be duplicates, they will be eliminated even if they are suppose to be there.

The full alter would be:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[mc_Workouts_GetActivities]
@WorkoutID                  bigint
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT d.ID, a.Description,
        CASE WHEN Reps = 0 THEN NULL ELSE Reps END AS Reps,
        CASE WHEN Sets = 0 THEN NULL ELSE Sets END AS Sets,
        CASE WHEN Minutes = 0 THEN NULL ELSE Minutes END AS Minutes,
        d.Comments, c.Name AS Category, a.CategoryID,
        (CASE WHEN v.ActivityID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS HasVideo,
        a.ID AS ActivityID
FROM mc_WorkoutDetails d
inner join (select Reps, Sets, Comments, Minutes, max(id) id
            from mc_WorkoutDetails
            group by Reps, Sets, Comments, Minutes ) q on q.id = d.id
        INNER JOIN mc_Activities a ON d.ActivityID = a.ID
        INNER JOIN mc_Activities_Categories c ON a.CategoryID = c.ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN mc_TrainerVideos v ON a.ID = v.ActivityID
WHERE (d.WorkoutID = @WorkoutID)
ORDER BY SortOrder, a.Description

RETURN @@ERROR
END
```

Comment: *What you can do is add a **joint** back to the same table using a group to **weed** out the duplicate rows.* Something on your mind, while you were writing this answer?

Comment: Yes, @Darin that makes sense. Thanks. But first, I will probably spend some time reviewing the code and data to understand what is happening in the data to cause this in the first place.

Comment: There I got rid of the joint.

Comment: What I would guess is more than likely you have an ajax script or a form that allows you to double click a button and it sends the insert twice.  What you can do is add some javascript to disable the button after a click.  That's what I've had to do in the past.  Also, it could be that someone just does the same set and enters the data twice?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's input. The general suggestions here were correct: I had two rows in the `mc_workoutDetails` table that referenced the same row in the `mc_Activities` table.

While the foreign key was part of a unique primary key, it was a compound key and so this column could contain duplicates as long as the other column in the key were different.